# Go HTTP Server for React, Angular, etc

Tags: reactjs, angular, http, go, webserver

I created this small HTTP Server in GO for static files:

```
func wrapHandler(h http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    h.ServeHTTP(srw, r)
    log.Printf("GET %s", r.RequestURI)
  }
}



func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", wrapHandler(
    http.FileServer(http.Dir("/static"))
  ))

  if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

It works perfectly with React and Angular `dist` files (after transpile them). However if I already selected a route e.g. http://example.org:8080/customers and click on refresh in the browser I got a 404 page not found. That is the only situation where my code is failing.

It happens because on React and Angular `index.html` acts as a front controller and can handle the routes. However to make it working I need to internally redirect all **not found** requests to index.html.

Since is the angular/react handling the route I wouldn't like to create a `http.HandleFunc` for each route created in the angular/react. I would like to something similar to `express` :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
app.use("*",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'static/index.html'));
});
```

or NGINX:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
```

Any clues on how to do it in go?

Comment: I notice you're forgetting to call `h(w, r)` in `wrapHandler()`, this preventing any calls from being sent to the fileserver.

Comment: You're right. I just forgot to put here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand how Go's http package handles route matching as it's a bit different from other languages/frameworks. `HandleFunc` uses ServeMux under the hood and (from the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux)):

> ServeMux is an HTTP request multiplexer. It matches the URL of each incoming request against a list of registered patterns and calls the handler for the pattern that **most closely matches the URL**. [emphasis mine]

Given this behavior, I would recommend creating explicit handlers for each folder in static (e.g. `css/`, `js/`), or putting all in a single subfolder of static, and then respond with your `index.html` file for all other requests (using the root route (`/`)). This works because requests with routes prefixed by `/css/` or `/js/` will more closely match the appropriate static handler routes, while all others will not and therefore only most closely match the root route. You just need to be sure not to create conflicting routes on your front-end.

This way any request explicitly for CSS/JS/image assets will be handled by serving the static directory and all other requests will be responded to with your React app.

Here's an example (leaving out your `wrapHandler` for simplicity):

```golang
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/index.html")
    })
    http.Handle("/js/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
    http.Handle("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

or if you want to be a bit more explicit:

```golang
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/index.html")
    })
    
    jsFs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/js"))
    http.Handle("/js/", http.StripPrefix("/js", jsFs))
    
    cssFs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/css"))
    http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css", cssFs))

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

My website works pretty much the same way (using Vue instead of React).

**An Improvement**

As mentioned above, you might consider putting all you static assets in a sub folder of your current `static/` folder. Consider structuring your files like this:

```
public/
  index.html
  static/
    css/
    js/
    img/
```

Which is the default file structure for built React apps (but `public` is called `build` by default).

This will let you use the above approach in a more streamlined way since you'll only need one fileserver handler for all static assets. Then you can use the following code:

```golang
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "public/index.html")
    })

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public/static/"))
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static", fs))

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still looking for an automatic way to handle these, but for now it answered my question

Comment: @JoaoGilbertoMagalhaes glad this helps, I've also updated the answer to include more detail on how to streamline the code a bit by rearranging your files.